# How can I deliberately reduce free memory in linux by a given amount?

Tags: linux, bash, memory

I am looking for a quick and dirty way to analyze how a memory intensive third party application behaves under reduced memory conditions and determine a "minimum viable free memory" threshold.

```
you@yours:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          993M       879M       113M       1.1M        15M       116M

you@yours:~$ hogMem 100 &
you@yours:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          993M       979M        13M       1.1M        15M       116M

you@yours:~$ date; runTheThing; date;
you@yours:~$ fg
you@yours:~$ ^C
you@yours:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          993M       879M       113M       1.1M        15M       116M
```

In the above, what could I use for `hogMem`?

I hope to do it with existing commands, without getting into a complicated programming problem.  Googling this issue gets me 1,000s of pages about how to get **more** free memory, not less.

**Update 2016/04/28 :**

So, I found a super convenient way to do this, thanks to the hint by @Cyrus

```
you@yours:~$ sudo mkdir -p /media/temporary_ram_disk
you@yours:~$ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/temporary_ram_disk/
you@yours:~$ sudo chown you:you /media/temporary_ram_disk/

you@yours:~$ cd /media/temporary_ram_disk/
you@yours:/media/temporary_ram_disk$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          993M       879M       113M       1.1M        15M       116M

you@yours:/media/temporary_ram_disk$ fallocate -l 100M empty_file_100M
you@yours:/media/temporary_ram_disk$ ls -l
total 5120
-rw-r--r-- 1 you you 5242880 Apr 28 12:05 empty_file_100M

you@yours:/media/temporary_ram_disk$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          993M       879M        13M       1.1M        15M       116M
```

So the `hogMem` I'm using is in fact `fallocate`  !

Comment: Which distribution and version do you use?

Comment: You can try http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano.  Thanks people.  These are all really great ideas.  I'm still looking at which to go with.

Comment: @Cyrus, your ramdisk suggestion disappeared, when I added my previous comment.  I think you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to see "how a memory intensive third party application behaves under reduced memory conditions," is to run it under reduced memory conditions.  On linux, this is easily done with `prlimit`.

For example, to see how `date` runs with its address space limited to 1,000,000 bytes, run:

```
$ prlimit -v1000000 date
Segmentation fault
```

To see how it runs with its address space limited to 10,000,000 bytes, run:

```
$ prlimit -v10000000 date
Wed Apr 27 12:00:13 PDT 2016
```

It is also possible to limit the target program's access to many other resources.  For example the maximum number of open files or the maximum CPU time can also be limited.

`prlimit` is included in the `util-linux` package.  For more details on its operation, see `man prlimit`.